# Multiply dropdown angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, drop-down-menu

on my web app, i need to have multiply dropdown box. All data is from json from my api. Ok, the my problem is, i know how to set data from api, but here i have 3 different url, one with country, second with states and third with city. Dropdown depending on selected country. on first drop down i need to select county (url: blabla/countries), then in second dropdown i need to set states for selected country (url: blabla/countries/countryId/states) and in third dropdown i need select city only for selected states (url: blabla/countries/countryId/states/statesId/city). 
I don't know how to add id from selected country or states to url for next dropdown box.

```js
 $http.get('url')
                .success(function(response)
        {$scope.countryes=response;});
```

```html
  <div>
        Country: 
        <select id="country" ng-model="country" ng-options="country.id as country.name for country in countryes">
          <option value=''>{{countryes.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        States <select id="city" ng-disabled="!country" ng-model="suburbs" ng-options="state as state.name for state in states"><option value='state'>Select</option></select>
    </div>
    <div>
        City <select id="suburb" ng-disabled="!suburbs" ng-model="suburb" ng-options="suburb for suburb in suburbs"><option value=''>Select</option></select>        
    </div>
```

Thnx to everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ng-change` for county and state select

```
   <div>
  Country:
  <select id="country" ng-model="country" ng-options="country.id as country.name for country in countryes" ng-change='getState()'>
    <option value=''>{{countryes.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  States
  <select id="city" ng-disabled="!country" ng-model="suburbs" ng-options="state as state.name for state in states"  ng-change='getCity()'>
    <option value='state'>Select</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
```

in controller ad new functions

```
$scope.getState = function(){
    //this function run when you select country
     $http.get('getStateUrl',{country: $scope.country})

}


$scope.getCity= function(){
     //this function run when you select state
     $http.get('getCityUrl',{state: $scope.suburbs})
}
```

Comment: thnx, but where set id?

Comment: I do this with ng resource and ng-change. And In first dropdown i have list of all country. Now problem is,  how to set id for next drop down?  Url Looks like this myapiurl/country/:countryID/states. I need to set to :countryid,  id of selected country.  I try add (countryid: @country.id) In ng resource but doesn't work.  Can someone explain me how to set id?  In another App i do this,  but there Was id on the Last position In url.  How to change when need to set id In the middle of url?  Thnx

Comment: you have model country id as ng-model='country', `$scope.country` is contry id

Comment: I do this,  but doesn't work .  They give me url something like this myapiurl/country/states (they delete countryID) or myapiurl/country/status?=1...  Thanke you for your time for helping me

Answer (score 0):

first thnx to @aseferov for help. 
If someone in future will have same questions this is my code, how i do this. 
This is my CTRL (i have three different drop down depending on ID from drop down before)

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'narudzbaResourceFactory', 'narudzbaResourceStatesFactory', 'narudzbaResourceStatesCityFactory',
function ($scope, routeParams, narudzbaResourceFactory, narudzbaResourceStatesFactory, narudzbaResourceStatesCityFactory) {

    narudzbaResourceFactory.query(function (res) {
        $scope.countries = res;
    });
    $scope.getState = function () {

        $scope.states = narudzbaResourceStatesFactory.query({country: $scope.country.id});

    };

    $scope.getCity = function () {
        $scope.cities = narudzbaResourceStatesCityFactory.query({state: $scope.state.id});

    };
```

And this is my factory

```
app.factory('narudzbaResourceFactory', ['$resource',
function ($resource) {
    var countries = $resource('/locationlist/countries', {
        query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true
        }
    });
    return countries;
}]);

app.factory('narudzbaResourceStatesFactory', ['$resource',
function ($resource) {
    var states = $resource('locationlist/countries/:country/states',  {country: '@country'}, {
        query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true
        }
    });
    return states;
}]);

app.factory('narudzbaResourceStatesCityFactory', ['$resource',
function ($resource) {
    var cities = $resource('/locationlist/states/:state/cities',
            {state: '@state'}, {
        query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true
        }
    });
    return cities;
}]);
```

And in the view i use it like this

```
  <div>
    Country: 
    <select id="country" ng-model="country" ng-options="country as country.name for country in countries track by country.id" ng-change="getState()">
        <option value='{{country.id}}'>{{country.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    States <select id="state" ng-disabled="!country" ng-model="state" ng-options="state as state.name for state in states track by state.id" ng-change="getCity()">
        <option value='{{state.id}}'>{{state.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    City <select id="city" ng-disabled="!state" ng-model="city" ng-options="city as city.name for city in cities track by city.id">
        <option value='{{city.id}}'>{{city.name}}</option></select>        
</div>
```